# Question about the subadditivity lemma

Tags: sequences-and-series

Please refer to [this page](https://www.comm.utoronto.ca/frank/notes/subadditivity.pdf) for the subadditivity lemma.

In short, a non-negative sequence $(a_n)$ is called subadditive if $a_{n+m}\leq a_n+a_m$ for $n,m\geq 1$. The subadditivity lemma states that if $(a_n)$ is non-negative and subadditive, then $a_n/n\to \inf\{a_n/n\}$.

The proof in the link doesn't use any specific theorem. But as the sequence converges to its infimum, I wonder if we can use monotone convergence theorem. it is bounded already (non-negative), so I only need to show if it's decreasing.

But to have $a_n/n\leq a_{n-1}/(n-1)\iff(n-1)a_n\leq na_{n-1}$,

we have to use the subadditivity: $(n-1)a_n\leq(n-1)(a_{n-1}+a_1)=(n-1)a_{n-1}+(n-1)a_1$.

It means we have to show that $(n-1)a_1\leq a_{n-1}$, but we have $a_{n-1}\leq (n-1)a_1$ by the subadditivity, so the only case is $a_{n-1}=(n-1)a_1$.

If $a_{n-1}<(n-1)a_1$, then we have no guarantee that $(a_n/n)$ is decreasing. But to be decreasing, it must be $a_n/n<a_1$ at some $n$ since $a_1$ is its upper bound.

How should I proceed from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot use the monotone convergence theorem because $(a_n/n)$ is not necessarily decreasing for a subadditive sequence $(a_n)$. A simple counterexample is
$$
 a_n = 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, \ldots
$$
which is subadditive because
$$
a_{n+m} \le 2 = 1 + 1 \le a_n + a_m 
$$
for all $n, m$. But
$$
 \frac {a_n}{n} = 1, 1, \frac 13, \frac 12, \frac 15, \frac 13, \ldots
$$
is not decreasing.